# Multiple facebook login in a application iPhone-sdk

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios4

I am using FBConnect in my application. It have four buttons and I want 4 users use our different facebook login in single application and single device according to button click. and after once login it did not ask username password again. So please can any one suggest me how i do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible for multiple login into Facebook in browser. Refer [here](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=161914247160203) for multiple login.

But Facebook supports one login at a time.Unless some trick or proxy server for login purpose in browser.

But **Facebook API** authentication is working on one access token (one login) at atime.

Comment: Thanks. But I am talking about the FBConnect iPhone SDK.

Comment: i m taking about FBConnect iPhone SDK only

Answer (score 0):

FBConnect will allow one login at at time. Once another session (login) is started, the last one is no longer valid.